# Unable to disable Entry via Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

In my Maui xaml I have an Entry control which is initially enabled and I want to disable it programmatically once the user has entered a correct value in the control.

But it is not

My xaml code looks like this

```
 <Entry
     x:Name="InputAnswer"
     Margin="0,0,20,0"
     FontSize="24"
     HorizontalOptions="Start"
     IsEnabled="{Binding IsWrong}"
     Keyboard="Numeric"
     MaxLength="5"
     Placeholder=""
     Text="{Binding InputAnswer}" />
```

My model class

```
  public class EquationWithInput: Equation, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public int? InputAnswer {  get; set; }
      public int CorrectAnswer{  get; set; }
      public bool IsWrong { get => InputAnswer == null ? true : InputAnswer != CorrectAnswer; }
      ...
  }
```

But when I check the results, the control is never disabled.  It appears the binding doesn't work, but it works everywhere else in this page for all the other properties.  E.g.  the `InputAnswer`.

So what do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the **EquationWithInput** class correctly implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raises the **PropertyChanged** event when the **InputAnswer** changes, since this indirectly affects the **IsWrong** property.

Here's how you can modify your **EquationWithInput** class to ensure that changes to **InputAnswer** properly notify the UI about updates to the **IsWrong** property as well:

```
public class EquationWithInput : Equation, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int? inputAnswer;
    public int? InputAnswer
    {
        get { return inputAnswer; }
        set
        {
            if (inputAnswer != value)
            {
                inputAnswer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputAnswer));
                // Since IsWrong depends on InputAnswer, it needs to notify the change as well.
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsWrong));
            }
        }
    }

    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    public bool IsWrong => InputAnswer == null || InputAnswer != CorrectAnswer;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh, that's it!  I thought I had tried this already, but I had it on the wrong property.  This works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you must invoke the `PropertyChanged`
event  when the `IsWrong` property is set but, in your case (that the `IsWrong` property depends on other property) you can invoke the `PropertyChanged` event from the `InputAnswer` property setter and the name parameter should be the name of the IsWrong property for example

```
public string InputAnswer
{
  set 
  {
      //other logic 
 
    OnPrepertyChanged(nameof(IsWrong));
  }
  //other logic
}
```